# Read from file in Java

Tags: java, methods

I have an assignment to create a payroll program that is read from a file and includes methods. I have first part complete, read the name, hourly wage, hours worked, and dependents.
Now I am completely lost how to have it read the above data and produce the following detail data:

- regular hours
- overtime hours
- regular pay
- overtime pay
- gross pay

Here is what I have so far...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Payroll {  
    public static void main(String [] arg) throws FileNotFoundException {
        double hourlyWage=0,hoursWorked=0.0, regularPay = 0,  grossPay=0, overtimePay = 0, overtimeHours=0, regularHours=0;
        int  dependents, count=0;
        String fName, lName;

        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("payroll.txt"));
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("weeklyData.txt"));


        while(inFile.hasNext()){
            fName = inFile.next();
            lName = inFile.next();
            hourlyWage = inFile.nextDouble();
            hoursWorked = inFile.nextDouble();
            dependents = inFile.nextInt();


        outFile.printf("%1s%10s\n", fName, lName);
        outFile.println("***************");
        outFile.printf("%5s\n%5s\n%5s\n", "Hourly Wage: $" + hourlyWage, "Hours Worked: " + hoursWorked, "Dependents: " + dependents);
        outFile.println("**************");
        outFile.printf("%10s%15s%15s%15s%13s\n", "Regular Hours   ", "Overtime Hours ", "Regular Pay", "Overtime Pay", " Gross Pay");
        outFile.println("\n\n                     ");

        }

        grossPay = (hoursWorked * hourlyWage);

        outFile.printf("%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s\n", regularHours, overtimeHours, regularPay, overtimePay, grossPay);

        outFile.close();
        inFile.close();

        System.out.println("Reading from file..." + count + " Employees");


     } 
      static double calculateOvertimePay(double hourWorked, double hourlyWage) {
         if(((hourWorked -40) * hourlyWage) * 1.5);
           }
      else {
        return 0.0;
   }
}
```

> ```
> 1Randy  Marchant
> 2**************
> 3Hourly Wage: $28.31
> 4Hours Worked: 37.25
> 5Dependents: 4
> 6**********************
> 7Regular Hours     Overtime Hours     Regular Pay       Overtime Pay   Gross Pay
>       0.0                 0.0             0.0
> ```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java

Comment: You need to call `Scanner.nextLine()` when you've read the last token on the current line.